# How to remove all Xcode local git branches but keep main?

Tags: xcode, git

I want to remove all Xcode local git branches but keep main, not manually since I have hundreds.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

- `cd <your project directory>`
- `rm -rf .git`

If you want add your remote repository again, you have to setup it again, but all your local branches will be deleted.